# How to find the paths between vertices with degree > 2 in a directed tree graph?

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx, vertices

I have no training in graph theory, so my terminology is poor. I have a directed tree graph that has "redundant nodes." I am defining "redundant nodes" as those with degree=2 in my tree graph. I would like to find an efficient way to return all the paths between all non-redundant nodes, preferably using NetworkX (Python) tools. This really simple graphic demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So given this graph, I'd like to return three paths (p1, p2, and p3) that represent the connections between 1->4, 5->4, and 4->7.

I  can write an algorithm to do this "manually", in the sense that I start at nodes with degree=1 and "walk" along the graph until I hit another non-degree=2 node. However, I suspect that there is already a formalized way to do this kind of analysis, but I can't seem to figure it out.

For more context, my graphs are much larger and more complicated as they're representations of river networks, something like this:

[image]

But they're always trees, no cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid that you've already hit the most effective way to do your mini-paths.  You can speed up the processing slightly by working backward from a confluence node, but that's about all you can improve.  Doing so will let you remove intermediate nodes a little more effectively than simply looking for source nodes (which you still have to do).  However, that algorithm is not as simple.  For now, I suggest that you stick with the simple design you already have.

---

- Put all nodes into a set `to_visit`.
- while `to_visit` is not empty:

  - node = to_visit.pop()
  - if node has degree 1:    # source node: find path to confluence

    - trace path until you hit a node of degree > 2.
    - delete all intermediate nodes from `to_visit`.
    - emit path.

Comment: Hm, I assumed this was a basic and common enough problem to have pre-built solutions. I appreciate your input and mean no offense, but how are you sure that there is no more effective way?

Comment: Just to be sure, I cruised through the `networkx` documentation.  Although this is a straightforward problem, it's not particularly common.  Anyone who needs such a graph usually pre-processes the data to remove those redundant nodes before building the graph, or immediately afterward (as you seem to want).  Most of the more general tree applications simply don't have redundant nodes by data design.

Comment: Fair enough, back to the drawing board I reckon!

Answer (score 1):

```
LOOP over all nodes
    calculate degree
    IF degree == 2
       add to vector deg2
LOOP over all nodes in deg2 to get src
    LOOP over all nodes in deg2 starting at src+1 to get dst
        find path from src to dst ( dijsktra algorithm )
```

Comment: Thanks, I already put something together that avoids the for loops by walking from the "root" of the tree toward the leaves, halting at confluences (i.e. degree !=2) and saving the nodes of each reach. I had considered the approach you laid out but am fairly confident that it is not optimal for my case. (I didn't share all the information I have in my question.)